# Querying a data warehouse based on a varible date

Tags: data-warehouse

I have a dimension table that tracks changes to an object similar to an employee object. However the employee has a "status" (Pending, active, inactive etc.) and start and end dates for each status which is tracked in another table in the source db.

There is no limit to how many times the status can update. It can go back and forth between statuses.

How do I model this if I wish to create a report such as employees with a given status on a specific day. If I use the status changes as the fact, I will only have the additional information from employee for dates the status changed on.

Do I need to create a fact table that updates daily with the current employee records and status?

Or can I create a fact table with effective from and to dates like in the dimension table?

Or am I way off on this and should be approaching it differently?

Comment: You need an *event feed* from source system with `employee_id, timestamp, old_status, new_status`.  You can build a **SDC 2** table with `employee_id, validfrom, validto, status`.

Comment: That's pretty much the model I've used for the status dimension, my issue is with combining the two dimensions. I understand how to do it if there is a relevant fact (a payment made for example) but I'm unsure on what to do when the fact is just a date.

Comment: More details posted, I hope it is more clear;)

Comment: If I want to generate a report that lists all active employees on the 1st of January 2019, do i need a row in the fact table for every employee and status for every date? This seems like it would be cumbersome, as you'd need a record for every employee for every day.

Do i need a fact table? Can I report directly against the dimension? From what I've read, this seems to be discouraged? EDIT: Sorry, acidentally submitted original comment and then couldn't edit due to 5 min rule, hadn't seen your update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you must decide is whether you will **poll** the employee or you get an **event feed** of the *employee  status change*.

The first option leads to simplified design, you load periodically (say once per day) the employee status of all employees and build your dimension.

Note that this is a aproximation, because the employee can swicht the status several times a day, but you consider only one status per day.

The tables is as follows

```
 employee_id, 
 validfrom_date, 
 validto_date, 
 status
```

The `validfrom_date` is the extraction date, `validto_date` is calculated. You discard all employees that do no change in the status.

The second option is more involved, but produce more exact results.

You load all status changes of all employees from the source system with exact timestamp, so it is possible to cover more changes per day.

Possible interface is:

```
 employee_id, change_timestamp, old_status, new_status
```

Note that the `old_status` is redundant and the value may be used to check if the interface is consistent.

The final table is similar to the previous one, only `timestamp`s are used instead of `date`s.

```
 employee_id, 
 validfrom_timestamp, 
 validto_timestamp, 
 status
```

Again the `validfrom_timestamp` is the timestamp from the event from the interface, the `validto_timestamp` is calulated.

In this setup a *periodical check of the consistence* of your dimension is recommended.

The problem - if some change event get lost, you never recover it. Through the time you may accumulate such errors. So say once per month you check, if your actual status of the dimension matches the status in the source system. If not you fix the difference.

Finally **do not speculate if this is fact or dimension table**. In the Kimball's model there is no strict distinction between them.

Take an `Employee` table. If you reports the employee status the role is *fact table*. If you use it to join to other fact tables the role is *dimension*.

Comment: Oh, ok, so it's valid to query both tables using date_param between validfrom_date and validto_date? I had read that I should only be querying against an indexed single date column.

Comment: Well if you manage to keep the `validfrom`and `validto` columns consistent, you may profit with high performant queries. Please provide link to your source to be able to discuss it.